# Converting the shape of a tensorflow matrix from (x,y,z) to (1,x,y,z)

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow

How to change the matrix from 3-D to 4-D. More specifically how to convert a matrix `A` with shape `(x, y, z)` to a matrix `B` with shape `(1,x,y,z)`?

Such that for example the element `A[7,3,5] == B[1,7,3,5]`

Comment: yes , I want to change the dimensions from 3 to 4 in other words the new matrix will be 4d where the first dimension is of size 1

Answer (score 2):

The [`tensorflow.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) function should be a perfect match:

```
new_matrix = tf.expand_dims(old_matrix, axis=0)
```